# Optimization of rewriting from AudioInputStream to ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, audio, mp3, inputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

There were few similar topics on stackoverflow but none of them seemed good enough for me. The problem is i have such a snippet of code:

```
        // AudioInputStream in;
        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = in.read(byteBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
            byteStream.write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        byte[] audioData = byteStream.toByteArray();
```

This code reads data of mp3 file and saves it to byte array, but takes about 10 seconds. Is there any possibility to store whole mp3 data into buffer in shorter time? 
I've tried to avoid passing the size of buffer or extend it but that caused additional problems (e.g. file was not read correctly).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd guess that reading the AudioInputStream is what takes most of the time, not writing it to the ByteArrayOutputStream. The optimization would therefore have to be done in the supplier of the AudioInputStream. Can you provide an example where you get the AudioInputStream?

Comment: I'm using JLayer so decoding of mp3 files is also a process which is not  done by code i've written  `AudioInputStream as = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);  
AudioFileFormat format = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);  
AudioFormat outFormat;  
if (format instanceof TAudioFileFormat) {  
    outFormat = decode(as.getFormat());  
   } else {  
    outFormat = in.getFormat();  
   }  
 AudioInputStream in= AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(outFormat, as);`

Comment: How long (in time) is the song? How big are the mp3 files?

Comment: If the mp3 is a compressed wav, the size of the file should be available. Do you know how to do this on wav files? I don't use JLayer so I can't say for sure it ends up being the same (after decoding steps).

Comment: Well, for song with length 2:53 operation takes 4200-4800ms . I do not want to copy all the file so filesize is not necessary - I need to extract only audio data (not tags, artwork etc) and draw a waveform on canvas. The problem is I dont know what size in bytes it really has, so i'm using this byte stream.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying data 3 times, you can avoid that by first checking the file size, allocating a byte array big enough, and reading into that directly.
It also helps a little bit to pre-allocate space in the ByteArrayOutputStream so it doesn't have to be increased in size many times.

If you can't get the file size up front, you can allocate a new byte[] for every block, and put them in a list, until you got them all. Then allocate the final array and copy all of them into the last array. *IF* you need a byte[] in the end. If you don't, there may be more efficient ways to proceed.

Comment: Well, checking the size of mp3 file is not a simple thing, because it also has information about the song, artwork data etc, so it can vary much, when actual data which i need (audio samples) is still the same size. I use ByteArrayOutputStream, because I do not have to know the size at the beggining.